# Why is this structure giving size as 24?

Tags: c

My code below prints 24 but size should be :
1+ 7  (pad) + 8 + 4 =20 ?

`

```
typedef struct data3
 {
   char        cval;
   double      dval;
   int         val;
 } structc_t;

//somewhere
printf("%d",sizeof(data3));
```

Comment: "Your code below" does not print anything. Your `sizeof(data3)` will not compile in C. Either `sizeof(structc_t)` or `sizeof(struct data3)`. Don't post fake code.

Comment: But it compiled and ran.
Why should it not ?
Actually I am learning from somwhere.

Comment: No, it didn't. If you "compiled and ran" it, then it was different in some way. You are supplying inaccurate claims and we have no means to figure out what part is inaccurate.

Comment: I don't know why you are saying but it is running in dev c++

Comment: Dev **C++**? Are you by any chance compiling your code as C++? In C++ `sizeof(data3)` will indeed compile. But your question is tagged [C], not [C++]. C and C++ are two completely different languages. If you used C++, but tagged your question as [C], then this is exactly what I meant when I said that you are supplying inaccurate claims.

Comment: Sorry sir my bad the file was named as cpp and I was doing all c stuff in it.
But can you tell why was it working c++ allows this ? why ?
thanks

Comment: something for you to know... a struct will always be a multiple of the largest field type contained within it, unless something like #pragma pack is used

Comment: @user3629249:You likely think about a union. For a struct padding is not defined by the standard and most likely just such as to have all fields aligned as required by the ABI. _Packing_ is not defined by the standard, but an extension of e.g. gcc. For the struct given, it is very likely as given by AnT's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1 + 7 (pad) + 8 + 4 + 4 (pad) = 24`. You are forgetting tail padding, which is there to make sure `struct data3` elements are aligned properly in an array. Your entire struct has to be aligned on 8-byte boundary, which means that its size should be divisible by 8.

C language guarantees the following relationship for arrays

```
sizeof(T[N]) == sizeof(T) * N
```

This immediately means that arrays cannot add their own padding between elements. If any inter-element padding is needed to properly align elements in an array, that padding *shall* be included into the individual array element. No way around it.

For this reason `sizeof(struct data3)` will include array-specific padding even if you never use `struct data3` in an array. This is what you see as tail padding in your struct.

(A globally-optimizing compiler can probably optimize it out, if you never use your `struct data3` in an array. But it is generally not worth it.)

Answer (score 1):

Not only each member of the `struct` has to be data aligned, but the `struct` itself has to aligned to the size of the largest member in the `struct`. So, padding is added to `struct data3` such that its size should be a multiple of the larger of the sizes of `char`, `double` and `int`.

Have a look at what the [C FAQ says about alignment](http://www.c-faq.com/struct/align.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is because, along with structure members, structure type variables will also have natural alignment.

Lets say if you allocate a array of this strcuture `data3 array[2]`
then see with your logic the double will be at  20 + 1 + 7 =28

And thus not at multiple of 8. Thus compiler will add 4 bytes (another padding ) to avoid this.

Multiple of 8 as double requires 8 bytes and thus to read it in one cycle it is needed on a 8 byte boundary.